# How to add additional options (not replace all options) for debhelper target?

Tags: debian, debian-based, debian-packaging, debhelper

I'd like to add an option to one of many debhelper targets (say "dh_strip_nondeterminism").

According to the dh man page (emphasis mine):

> To override dh_command, add a target named override_dh_command to the
> rules file. When it would normally run dh_command, dh will instead
> call that target. **The override target can then run the command with**
> **additional options**, or run entirely different commands instead. See
> examples below.

It isn't clear to me how to run the same target with all original options, plus one new option.

If I add this to my `debian/rules` file, should this persist all previous options?

```
override_dh_strip_nondeterminism:
    dh_strip_nondeterminism -v
```

It appears that the `-v` replaces any other arguments that might have been previously supplied to this target. How do I persist them?